# How to index float/double values in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 8.11 because of Java 8 and need to index float/double values. But I can find only `NumericDocValuesField` class which accepts only integer/long types.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene doesn't support direct indexing of float or double values because of their imprecise nature, one common approach is to convert your float/double values to long or int by scaling them:

```java
double originalValue = 123.456;
long scaledValue = (long) (originalValue * 1000);

document.add(new NumericDocValuesField("field", scaledValue));
```

So you decide on a precision level that you care about

Comment: I hope it helped! @devaskim